# Terraform - Google Internal Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

Does Terraform support Google's Internal Load Balancer?
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/internal/

Answer (score 5):

As of September 2017, it certainly does! Unfortunately, the documentation for it is not that great.

Here's a very rough example, might not just work via copy/paste!

```
resource "google_compute_instance_group" "elasticsearch-cluster" {
  name        = "elasticsearch-cluster"
  description = "Terraform test instance group"

  instances = [
    "${google_compute_instance.elasticsearch-compute-instance.*.self_link}"
  ]

  named_port {
    name = "elasticsearch-api"
    port = "9200"
  }

  named_port {
    name = "elasticsearch-transport"
    port = "9300"
  }

  zone = "us-central1-a"
}

resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "elasticsearch-forwarding-rule" {
  name   = "elasticsearch-lb"
  load_balancing_scheme = "INTERNAL"
  backend_service = "${google_compute_region_backend_service.elasticsearch-lb.self_link}"
  ports  = [ "9200", "9300" ]
}

resource "google_compute_region_backend_service" "elasticsearch-lb" {
  name             = "elasticsearch-lb"
  protocol         = "TCP"
  timeout_sec      = 10
  session_affinity = "NONE"

  backend {
    group = "${google_compute_instance_group.elasticsearch-cluster.self_link}"
  }

  health_checks = ["${google_compute_health_check.elasticsearch-healthcheck.self_link}"]
}

resource "google_compute_health_check" "elasticsearch-healthcheck" {
  name               = "elasticsearch-healthcheck"
  check_interval_sec = 5
  timeout_sec        = 5

  tcp_health_check {
    port = "9200"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It technically does, in the sense that it provides you with the relevant functions to run it:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_target_pool.html

Unfortunately, the documentation on it is quite poor and the layout of the functions mean that you have to set up a number of interdependent health checks, target pools, backend handlers and forwarding rules to achieve it, very different to how straightforward the rest of it is. The error messages displayed on `terraform plan` and `apply` are also rather unhelpful.

Currently I'm trying to setup a `environment.tf` that replicates an existing load balancer I manually setup and it's proving to be serious trial and error challenge. Hashicorp need to add a lot more use cases and explanations to their docs.